# Why doesn't webservice support accentuated letters?

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, java-me, wsdl

I set the `datatype` of the returned value in the `wsdl` file to be of `xsd:anyType` :

```
<message name="getEtapeProspResponse">
    <part name="return" type="xsd:anyType"/>
</message>
```

The `PHP` function which the `webservice` calls returns a String which is constructed from the selected columns from a MySQL table. And one of the columns has a `datatype` of `text` :

```
function getEtapeProsp($user,$motpasse)
    {
        $user_code    = verifyUser($user, $motpasse) ;
        $resultat="";
        if ( $user_code != null) 
        {
            $datejour = date("Y-m-d");
            $connec   = mysql_connect("192.168.1.123:3306", "root", "mysqlroot");
            mysql_select_db("finance",$connec);
            $query    = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM etape_prospection INNER JOIN type_prospection ON etape_prospection.type_prosp_id = type_prospection.type_prosp_id WHERE prosp_id IN (SELECT prosp_id FROM transfert WHERE user_code ='".$user_code ."' AND date_transfert='".$datejour."') order by etape_prospection.prosp_id");
            while($ligne = mysql_fetch_array($query))
                {
                     $resultat .= $ligne['etape_prosp_id'].';';
                     $resultat .= $ligne['type_prosp_lib'].';';
                     $resultat .= convertDateFormatHH($ligne['etape_prosp_date']).';';
                     $resultat .= $ligne['etape_prosp_comment'].';'; // this is the text column
                     $resultat .= $ligne['prosp_id'].';';
                     $resultat .= "\r\n";
                }
        }
        else
        {
            $resultat = "Login ou mot de passe incorrect" ;
        }
        return $resultat;
    }
```

In the database the value of the "etape_prosp_comment" has an accentuated letter , é.
The problem is that when I call the webservice from my `J2ME` application then an exception is thrown. But if I don't insert any accentuated letters in the `column` then the webservice is ok.

So how to resolve this accentuated letters problem ?

Comment: I'm no php expert, but maybe you can encode the information. Special characters may be a problem all the time when dealing with webservices.

Comment: Which exception is thrown? What does the XML message you receive from your server look like?

Comment: You mean `accented characters`. Accentuated would be more along the lines of "bold", "italic", etc... Have you checked that character sets match throughout the entire http pipeline (client->php->database->php->client)? A single change in character set anywhere in that chain will mangle the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Text contains *characters* like a, b, c, d, e or é (in your case) etc. All characters that a system supports form together a *character set*. A *character encoding* then defines how a character is serialized into a byte representation (what value, how many bytes will the value be stored in etc).

This is where you get the problem, in the encoding. Your characters get transformed to bytes and then from the bytes you have to get back the characters. If the web service and the client do not use the same character encoding, the web service can not convert the bytes from the client into characters, and vice-versa; you will either get errors or malformed character strings.

I'm not a PHP developer, but the following article contains some pertinent information about addressing the issue: [Character Sets / Character Encoding Issues](http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/charsets).

That article references another good one about character sets (although a bit old, from 2003): [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), so make sure you read this first.

The encoding you should be going for is UTF-8, mainly because that's the encoding mandated by the web service interoperability guide, along with UTF-16; [see rule R1012 of the Basic Profile](http://www.ws-i.org/Profiles/BasicProfile-1.0-2004-04-16.html#refinement16457984).